# Setting VPN when the built-in setting is absent/hidden

Tags: vpn

I know Android has native support for PPTP VPN, but I'm trying to set a custom PPTP VPN on an Android TV Box which has the setting hidden. Does anyone know if there's another way to enable this (without rooting)?

Any thought appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure but try the apps : 'drony' or 'psiphon'. I personally use psiphon in my college. I recommend psiphon, its easy to operate upon.

Comment: These don't allow setting custom PPTP VPNs, right?

Comment: Like I said I don't know for sure but you can try 'Pshiphon or Drony' as they let you connect without having to root your device. They are small apps, look for it yourself :P

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: I've just tried both, but neither allows me to set a custom PPTP VPN server.

Comment: Well I am sorry then.